# How to prevent module coupling in very large webpack project?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am working on a very large javascript framework (approx 1000 javascript files). Which is currently built using Webpack.  I have identified that some parts of the app are core modules, and other parts are components that use the core.

I would like to prevent developers from coupling the non-core modules and the core modules.  And generally prevent inter module coupling outside of what the module exports.

When I say modules, I am not referring to a single js file which is an es6 module.  Rather I am referring to a folder that contains React components, Reducers, Sagas et. all that all together constitue a logical module.

What I want is that each "module" could be a folder containing an index.js file at it's root which exports what that module wants to expose.  Somehow I want to prevent other modules from reaching into that modules folder and importing "internal" files.  I.e. I want to limit other modules to only importing what is exported by the root index.js.

To illustrate:

```
/src/framework/core
    ./index.js
    ./someInternalFile.js

/src/framework/components/dataGrid
```

I don't want the dataGrid module above to be able to access the internal file.  Only what is exported in index.js

One approach would be to have sepearate webpack configs to build the core module into npm modules and use file: references in package.json.  However this adds a build step and would mean that if developers change core they need to re-build core and re-run npm install and then restart the webpack-dev-server.

This is severely limiting as it becomes a very slow developer experience.  Ideally I would like to acheive this logical separation of modules but maintain the webpack/filewatcher/hot/redeploy experience we currently enjoy.

Is there another way I can acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to address this issue is to break your application into multiple npm packages.  To reduce the overhead of doing this you may want to consider a "mono repo" (AKA "multi-package repo".)  This essentially allows you to package modules in your application into separate npm packages but keep the module hot loading and other things you want through the magic of symbolic links.  Essentially you make a symbolic link in your node_modules folder to the other modules inside your repo.

I have found a number of tools that do this:

- https://github.com/clux/symlink
- https://github.com/lerna/lerna
- https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/
- https://github.com/boltpkg/bolt